# Exporting tables to csv changes file extension

Tags: vba, csv, ms-access

I'm trying to export all my tables, from my access database, to separate .csv-files. I have a loop that runs through all tables and by using TransferText I want to create a .csv-file for each table.

I am able to create a single file by writing the TransferText method.

```
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "ExportCsv", [Table name], filePath + "Test.csv", True
```

But when I'm trying to create a loop to generate a file for each table I get into trouble. (Filepath is set to desktop)

```
' Loops through all tables and extracts them as .csv-files    
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
Set db = CurrentDb
For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
    ' ignore system and temporary tables
    If Not (tdf.Name Like "MSys*" Or tdf.Name Like "~*") Then
        ' Export table as CSV
        'MsgBox (tdf.Name)
        fileName = tdf.Name & ".csv"
        DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "ExportCsv", tdf.Name, filePath + fileName, True

    End If
Next
Set tdf = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

Doing it like this gives me Error '3011' saying it can't find the object. Then it gives me the object name: [table name]#csv. So for some reason it changes ".csv" to "#csv".

If I remove the file extension from the file name all I get is Error 3027 saying that the object or database is read-only.

Does anyone know if there is a solution to my problem or another way to do the same thing? Or am I gonna have to go a completely different route?

EDIT:

Other tested variations

```
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "ExportCsv", tdf.Name, "C:/tempFile.csv", True 
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "ExportCsv", tdf.Name, "C:/" & tdf.Name & ".csv", True
```

: Gives a "#csv" error.

```
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "ExportCsv", tdf.Name, "C:/tempFile", True
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "ExportCsv", tdf.Name, "C:/" & tdf.Name, True
```

: Gives a read only error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after lots of trial and error I have found a way that works for me.

With some inspiration from @Gustav I went with creating .xls files, which for some reason works. And then convert those files with a custom script to .csv-files. Then I remove the .xls files leaving only my .csv-files left.

So my loop now looks like this:

```
For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
    ' ignore system and temporary tables
    If Not (tdf.Name Like "MSys*" Or tdf.Name Like "~*") Then
        ' Export as xls-files
        fileName = tdf.Name & ".xls"
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, tdf.Name, filePath & env & fileName, True

        ' Convert xls-files to .csv and remove the xls-files.
        ConvertXls2CSV (filePath & env & fileName)
        VBA.Kill filePath & env & fileName
    End If
Next
```

And here is the converting code: (Credit to: https://www.devhut.net/2012/05/14/ms-access-vba-convert-excel-xls-to-csv/)

```
Function ConvertXls2CSV(sXlsFile As String)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim oExcel          As Object
    Dim oExcelWrkBk     As Object
    Dim bExcelOpened    As Boolean    'Was Excel already open or not
    'Review 'XlFileFormat Enumeration' for more formats
    Const xlCSVWindows = 23 'Windows CSV Format
    Const xlCSV = 6 'CSV
    Const xlCSVMac = 22 'Macintosh CSV
    Const xlCSVMSDOS = 24 'MSDOS CSV

    Set oExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")    'Bind to existing instance of Excel

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then    'Could not get instance of Excel, so create a new one
        Err.Clear
        'On Error GoTo Error_Handler
        Set oExcel = CreateObject("excel.application")
        bExcelOpened = False
    Else    'Excel was already running
        bExcelOpened = True
    End If

    'On Error GoTo Error_Handler
    oExcel.ScreenUpdating = False
    oExcel.Visible = False   'Keep Excel hidden from the user
    oExcel.Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set oExcelWrkBk = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(sXlsFile)
    'Note: you may wish to change the file format constant for another type declared
    'above based on your usage/needs in the following line.
    oExcelWrkBk.SaveAs Left(sXlsFile, InStrRev(sXlsFile, ".")) & "csv", xlCSVWindows, Local:=True
    oExcelWrkBk.Close False

    If bExcelOpened = False Then
        oExcel.Quit
    End If

Error_Handler_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oExcelWrkBk = Nothing
    Set oExcel = Nothing
    Exit Function

Error_Handler:
    MsgBox "The following error has occurred." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
            "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
            "Error Source: ConvertXls2CSV" & vbCrLf & _
            "Error Table: " & sXlsFile & vbCrLf & _
            "Error Description: " & Err.Description, _
            vbCritical, "An Error has Occurred!"
    Resume Error_Handler_Exit

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This is known limitation. TransferText doesn't like convoluted filenames.

So, *export* to a simple filename, then *rename* that file to its final name:

```vb
ExportFinal = "YourFinalName.csv"
ExportTemp = "FileToRename.csv"

DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "ExportCsv", tdf.Name, ExportTemp, True

VBA.FileCopy ExportTemp, ExportFinal
VBA.Kill ExportTemp
```

Comment: Unfortunately it seems like it doesn't matter how you write the filename in the TransferText, because it appears it doesn't like being in a for loop. It doesn't matter what I give the tempfile for name, as long as it don't like dots before the file extension while being in a loop it will never write a correct file name.

Comment: I'm not sure, what you mean. But try to use a different temp filename for each loop.

Comment: That also gives me an error. If I set the table name as the file name and add ".csv" I get the "#csv" problem. If I don't add the file extension I get a "Database or object is read only".

Comment: Are you exporting multiple tables? If so can you show me your code?

Comment: No, but you could edit your question to hold your revised code.