# Dot inside VBA string of an Access application gets interpreted as a number sign upon execution

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm working on a small Access database application that, among other things, exports a csv file when requested by the user.

The csv file should be created by the following code:

```
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "CSVexport", "tblExport", sLoc & Format(Date, "ddMMyyyy") & "_" & category & "_Export.csv", True
```

After fixing an issue with the data source part of the export (changed it from a query to a table), the `_Export.csv` part suddenly gets interpreted by Access as `_Export#csv`.

The error I'm getting:

> Run-Time error '3011': The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object '03022020_AluKippers_Export#csv'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell  its name and path correctly . If '03022020_AluKippers_Export#csv' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator.

I have no idea what's causing this.

Update: When changing the file extension to .txt, I get the same error. When using anything else after the dot, I get the cannot update error. I suspect the error may have something to do with the saved specification CSVexport...

Comment: Perhaps you need to escape it like `\.`

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611336/3820271

Comment: When changing the file extension to .txt, I get the same error. When using anything else after the dot, I get the cannot update error.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. The export specification I created, used the dot as the decimal symbol. After changing the decimal symbol back to `,` and the field delimiter from `,` to `;`, the code in my question worked as expected.